# How to save this list to a text file in Python

Tags: python, python-re

```
import urllib.request
import re
import json
import csv
x = 4
search_keyword = input("Enter the keyword ")
html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results? 
search_query=" + search_keyword + "&sp=EgIIAQ%253D%253D")
video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
for i in video_ids:
    print("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + i, end = ' ')
```

I am new to Python and recently found a tutorial how to find YouTube links in Python and I want to save the list of the links to a text file, but it gives me a error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Can you double check your indentation? and post the full traceback?

Comment: @12944qwerty how would i do that im new to stackoverflow i fixed indentation

Comment: The full traceback is the error you got. Please paste the entire error

Comment: @12944qwerty the error i got was TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @12944qwerty oh great that worked! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to write the video links to a text file, but I noticed you're importing the `csv` module (technically you won't need that here)

To avoid type errors in case your object is `None` you could explicitly build out a list of the video links:

```
video_urls = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + i for i in video_ids or []]
```

note the `video_ids or []` part is in case the `video_ids` object itself is `None`.

then save it to an output text file:

```
with open('out1.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('\n'.join(video_urls))
```

with Python 3 using the `pathlib` module, it becomes even easier (this is just a shortcut which wraps the same logic above):

```
from pathlib import Path

Path('out2.txt').write_text('\n'.join(video_urls))
```